# Regular expression for decimal number

Tags: c#, regex, decimal

I need to validate a `textbox` input and can only allow decimal inputs like: `X,XXX` (only one digit before decimal sign and a precision of 3).

I'm using C# and try this `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`?

Comment: Why would you use regular expressions here instead of the framework solution (`decimal.TryParse`)?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
^[0-9]([.,][0-9]{1,3})?$
```

It allows:

```
0
1
1.2
1.02
1.003
1.030
1,2
1,23
1,234
```

BUT NOT:

```
.1
,1
12.1
12,1
1.
1,
1.2345
1,2345
```

Comment: Replacing [0-9] with \d cuts out 3 characters (6 total) and does the same thing.

Comment: +1 but wouldn't it be good to accept .1 as this is a valid representation of 0.1 (tested with Decimal.Parse)?

Comment: The simplest version of this would be "\d(\.\d{1,3})?" but using "\d(?:\.\d{1,3})?" will mean that a group is not stored.

Comment: This will work only if the locale settings of the user uses . as a decimal separator. It will break if it's , (in fr-FR, for instance...)

Comment: To allow for '1.' and '1,' I have changed the regular expression to ^[0-9]{1}([\.\,]|([\.\,][0-9]{1,3}))?$

Comment: why not `[0-9]+...`?

Comment: [0-9] and \d are not the same!

Answer (score 24):

There is an alternative approach, which does not have I18n problems (allowing ',' or '.' but not both): [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/9zbda557).

Just try converting, ignoring the value.

```
bool IsDecimalFormat(string input) {
  Decimal dummy;
  return Decimal.TryParse(input, out dummy);
}
```

This is significantly faster than using a regular expression, see below.

(The overload of [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ew0seb73) can be used for finer control.)

---

Performance test results: Decimal.TryParse: 0.10277ms, Regex: 0.49143ms

Code (`PerformanceHelper.Run` is a helper than runs the delegate for passed iteration count and returns the average `TimeSpan`.):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using DotNetUtils.Diagnostics;

class Program {
    static private readonly string[] TestData = new string[] {
        "10.0",
        "10,0",
        "0.1",
        ".1",
        "Snafu",
        new string('x', 10000),
        new string('2', 10000),
        new string('0', 10000)
    };

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Action parser = () => {
            int n = TestData.Length;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                decimal dummy;
                count += Decimal.TryParse(TestData[i], out dummy) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        };
        Regex decimalRegex = new Regex(@"^[0-9]([\.\,][0-9]{1,3})?$");
        Action regex = () => {
            int n = TestData.Length;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                count += decimalRegex.IsMatch(TestData[i]) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        };

        var paserTotal = 0.0;
        var regexTotal = 0.0;
        var runCount = 10;
        for (int run = 1; run <= runCount; ++run) {
            var parserTime = PerformanceHelper.Run(10000, parser);
            var regexTime = PerformanceHelper.Run(10000, regex);

            Console.WriteLine("Run #{2}: Decimal.TryParse: {0}ms, Regex: {1}ms",
                              parserTime.TotalMilliseconds, 
                              regexTime.TotalMilliseconds,
                              run);
            paserTotal += parserTime.TotalMilliseconds;
            regexTotal += regexTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Overall averages: Decimal.TryParse: {0}ms, Regex: {1}ms",
                          paserTotal/runCount,
                          regexTotal/runCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: That’s not only faster, it’s much cleaner.

Comment: great solution!

Answer (score 8):

```
\d{1}(\.\d{1,3})?

Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{1}»
   Exactly 1 times «{1}»
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\.\d{1,3})?»
   Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «?»
   Match the character “.” literally «\.»
   Match a single digit 0..9 «\d{1,3}»
      Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{1,3}»


Created with RegexBuddy
```

Matches:
1
1.2
1.23
1.234

Comment: you can even leave out the {1}

Comment: You still have \d{1} instead of \d

Answer (score 6):

In general, i.e. unlimited decimal places:

`^-?(([1-9]\d*)|0)(.0*[1-9](0*[1-9])*)?$`

Answer (score 1):

I just found `TryParse()` has an issue that it accounts for thousands seperator.  Example in En-US, 10,36.00 is ok.  I had a specific scenario where the thousands seperator should not be considered and hence regex `\d(\.\d)` turned out to be the best bet. Of course had to keep the decimal char variable for different locales.

Comment: Use the overload of `Decimal.TryParse` that takes a `NumerStyles` parameter, and *don't* include `NumerStyles.AllowThousands`.

Answer (score 0):

As I tussled with this, TryParse in 3.5 does have NumberStyles:  The following code should also do the trick without Regex to ignore thousands seperator.

```
double.TryParse(length, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint,CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out lengthD))
```

Not relevant to the original question asked but confirming that TryParse() indeed is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET, I recommend to dynamically build the regular expression with the decimal separator of the current cultural context:

```
using System.Globalization;

...

NumberFormatInfo nfi = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
Regex re = new Regex("^(?\\d+(" 
                   + Regex.Escape(nfi.CurrencyDecimalSeparator) 
                   + "\\d{1,2}))$");
```

You might want to pimp the regexp by allowing 1000er separators the same way as the decimal separator.