# MaskedTextBox and hexadecimal

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, maskedtextbox

How can I create a MaskedTextBox for accepting hexadecimals and spaces?

I am using Windows Forms in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using KeyDown event.
The KeyEventArgs.SuppressKeyPress will handle exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

Simple: you can't.

Not with the standard [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask.aspx).

Comment: Is there no validations on MaskedTextBox? Even Java AWT has!

Comment: I guess you could try to intercept the `KeyPress` event and check if the character being pressed is a valid hex char, but then again, if you do this, you could do with a simple textbox.

Comment: I second this KeyPress intercept idea.  You could use the simple textbox and match the character against a regex [0-9a-fA-F].  If it doesn't match, set e.Handled to true to cancel the keystroke.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to match the input against a regular expression in the Textbox.Validating event handler.

I've also used a homegrown "RegexMaskedTextBox" solution which I've posted in Stack Overflow question *[Restricting the characters in the text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647371/restricting-the-characters-in-the-text-box/5653711#5653711)*.

Comment: The Validating event threats any input key? I want to ignore others keys.

Comment: Doing a standard regex match on the validation event would be after the fact and therefore not ignore keys.  Checkout the link I just posted, I think that may do what you want or at least send you down the right path.