# C# RegEx for decimal number

Tags: c#, regex, textbox, decimal

I'm trying to make a Regular expression for a textbox which should only allow either only digits or decimals. For example, I should be able to enter both 10 and 10,350.

The decimal seperator I'll use is "," and the decimal length don't need a limit.

Anyone knows how I can make such a RegEx?

Comment: Why not just use decimal.TryParse or double.TryParse?

Comment: @Shurdoof, you should make that into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd go for `decimal.TryParse()` too, but if you really need a RegEx then something like this should work: `(\d+(,\d*)?)`

Comment: Don't forget to anchor it, eg: `^\d+(?:,\d+)?\z`

Comment: @Qtax, good point, and actually it is not quite clear if something like `4,` or `,56` should match as well. And looking at the related topics, there is a similar question being answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number

Answer (score 1):

Just use `decimal.TryParse` or `double.TryParse`.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use it in many place in your project you can make new TextBoxcontrol it accept just number and make ',' when even the '.' clicked, and you can make test on it when it lostfocus()

Answer (score 0):

Here's your regex:

```
^[\d]+,?[\d]*$
```

check if it matches what's in your textbox.

Comment: Would match on the string `,,,1,,,`