# Extracting double/decimal number from string?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, extract

I need to extract the value `33345.002` from the following string:

```
"ABC(MAX)(33345.002)"
```

How can I perform this in C#?

I tried handling it in SQL but was picking up the (MAX) too so now I'm gonna try C#.
Thanks
.
.
.

This is the closest so far :

```
string temp = "YYY(33345.002)(gg)YYYY";
temp = Regex.Replace(temp, "[^.0-9]", "");
double num;
bool success = Double.TryParse(temp, out num);

if (success)
{
//do what ever to the number}
```

but there is a problem, some of the numbers have zeros in front of them. like: 00033.33

Comment: What have you tried? What have you searched for? -1 because this is asked so frequently (and in countless subtle variations).

Comment: First I tried doing it in SQL:
Substring('ABC(MAX)(33345.002)',CHARINDEX('(','ABC(MAX)(33345.002)'),Len('ABC(MAX)(33345.002)'))
BUT it is grabbing the (MAX) too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really pretty simple.
Declare the characters you want to grap [0-9]/"0123456789" as a constant in C#
loop through the string, example:

```
public bool TryParseDouble(string input, out double value){
  if(string.IsNullorWhiteSpace(input)) return false;
  const string Numbers = "0123456789.";
  var numberBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  foreach(char c in input) {
    if(Numbers.IndexOf(c) > -1)
      numberBuilder.Append(c);
  }
  return double.TryParse(numberBuilder.ToString(), out value);
}
```

Ofcoarse this could be enhanced (perhaps just parse out the first number, or return an array of doubles parsing out all numbers) - not to mention it will parse out multiple decimals which is not exactly what you want.

The same technique can be used in T-SQL as well with looping over the string, declaring the valid values then using 'in'.

EDIT: On second thought
    Regex.Match(input, @"\d+(.\d+)?") 
would extract double/decimal from string then you could just use double.Parse if a match is found :).

EDIT 2: Btw for some silly reason '\ .' gets escaped as '.' on Stack Overflow. Just note that the decimal in the regex is escaped (just . matches anything)
Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need the same regex (including the enhancements mentioned) as provided as the top answer by `J-16 SDiZ` for this SO: [Regular expression for decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number), but without the `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end.

Next time it might be worth searching a bit on SO or Google first :)

Comment: What if the length of digit is not fixed
i.e.  C(MCX)(33.09992)

Comment: yes, sorry, ignored that bit (was bedtime here in the UK). just change {1,3} to +.