# Regular Expression For Decimal Value

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regular expression for decimal input, which can take 4 digits before decimal or comma and 2 digits after decimal/comma. 5 digit number without decimal is invalid. Also can accept null.

Correct Values can be:

> 1, 1111, 2222.56, 0.99, 9999.5

Invalid

> 88888, 8.888,

Validation show also include comma along with decimal.

If possible, then also explain the expression.

Comment: Already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Regex.IsMatch(strInput, @"[\d]{1,4}([.,][\d]{1,2})?");
```

and explain:

```
[\d]{1,4}    any character of: digits (0-9) between 1 and 4 times

[.,]         any character of: '.', ','

[\d]{1,2}    any character of: digits (0-9) between 1 and 2 times

(...)?       match the expression or not (zero or one)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Is it possible for u to explain the regex. I want to know about each and every description.

Answer (score 3):

```
^-?(0|[1-9]\d{0,3})([,\.]\d{1,2})?$
```

BEFORE COMMA:

^ - beginning of the string

-? - there may be zero or one negative sign

0 - decimal may starts with only single zero at the beginning...

| - or ...

[1-9] - with any digit from 1 to 9

\d{0,3} - followed by any 3 digits

AFTER COMMA:

[,.] - there may be "," or "."

\d{1,2} - followed by 1 or 2 digits

(...)? - zero or one time

$ - end of the string

Answer (score 1):

```
[0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9]{1,2})?
```

This means, 1 to 4 digits, and then optionally both a decimal point and 1 to 2 digits.

Comment: I want comma also with decimal

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `\d{4}[,\.]\d{2}`
or `\d+([,\.]\d+)?` for any decimal

Comment: This one "\d{4}[,\.]\d{2}" only returns true if exact 9999.55 is matching, in all the other cases it is returning false. Ideally 1, 12, 137, 6544, 7.23 all should be valid but 99999, 9.369 should not be

Answer (score 0):

We can do code for checking Stirng value contains Decimal points by following code

```
    Dim Success As Boolean
    If text.Contains(".") Then
        Dim result As Integer = Split(text, ".")(1)
        If result > 0 Then
            Success = True      'Containing Decimal Points greater than
        Else
            Success = False     'Containing "0" as Decimal Points 
        End If
    End If
    Return Success
```

Comment: this question was tagged `C#`. Is this Basic?