# How to do a regex that requires or not a point between 2 numbers?

Tags: regex, replace

I wish to realise a regex that requires or not a point between 2 numbers.
I want to manage int and double numbers: the user can put a number such as "1" or also "1.5"
Thanks.

Comment: [Regular expression for decimal number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number) May not be an *exact* duplicate, but it is close enough, and there are many similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexepr:

`d+([,.]d+)?`

Comment: Note that in this way leading 0s may occur:

Answer (score 0):

The following will do the job:

```
^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]+)?$
```

**EDIT**

- fixed leading zero case
- [demo](http://regexr.com?31kmo)

Comment: Hi, I'm on visual studio and if I put "5.0" I obtain very heigh values; if I put "5" I obtain correct values.
I do a double.Parse from a string. Is it for this reason?

Comment: I added a demo, both "5" and "5.0" strings match. What kind of high values are you talking about? Can you post your code?

Comment: I think I founded the error.
If I put "5", a messagebox shows "5".
If I put "5.0", it shows "50".
I converted the string typed in the textbox in this way: double.Parse(myinput.Text);