# RegularExpression for decimal number

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression for decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number)

The column of my table having numeric(18,3) datatype.So I created the validation 
Expression like this Exp: `"^\d+([\.][0-9]{0,3})?$"` .Is it right?I want user to enter only number not character.

Either

```
1
1.0
1.12
1.123
11.23
123.123
```

Comment: Seems ok to me, although you are not checking the length of the integer part. In theory someone could write 123456789012345678901234567890.123 and your regular expression would accept it, but your database wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the simpler regex

```
^\d+.?\d{0,3}$
```

If you want to check whether your regex is correct check it with [regexplanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) on your testcases.

Comment: This will match `123.` for example.

Comment: @M42 I think `123.` is a valid number, at least I always use this form as floating point literals and it's taken as `123.0`.

Comment: In fact `123.` is a valid number but OP didn't say it want to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below one:

```
^\d{1,18}(?:\.\d{1,3})?$
```

***Update:***
Instead of use a regex to validate a number, you could just parse the input to a number and then compare it.

Comment: This will match numbers with 18 digit in integer part plus 3 digit in decimal part. I think the max length must be 18 included decimal part.

Comment: @M42 Yep, your point is right, but it's hard to do it with regex, do you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
^\d{1,18}|(?=.{3,19})\d+\.\d{1,3}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote it as `"^\d{1,15}(\.\d{0,3})?$"`. It is working properly.