# Regular expression for decimal?

Tags: c#, javascript

I want to avoid characters like "^+%&/!'&(" in the textbox(decimal).
What is the correct regular expression?

For instance:
Valid: 1,3 or 1,34 or 1
İnvalid: ^4,^' or %2,4 or !!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number?rq=1

Comment: Do you want to allow things like "1.2.4"?

Comment: What have you tried ? This sounds more like a request for someone to code it for you, not a question.

Comment: How about input type=number ?

Comment: @adeneo still lets you enter in non numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
(\d+[.,])?\d+
```

This means zero or more digits followed optionally by a decimal point, and then one or more digits.

Edit: Updated to include commas and at least one decimal before the decimal point if the decimal point is present

Comment: This should be `\d*[.,]?\d+` to allow for a comma as the decimal separator (as OP wants).