# Specific decimal number regular expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have regular expression validator with expression like:

```
^\d{1,4}(\,\d{1,3})?$
```

I wan`t to validate next formats:

1. Decimal numbers with max 3 decimal places like 0,125 1,15, 0,5 but not(1,1234) that is ok but, user can write 5 digits like (12345, 54321 ... )
2. Exclude 0, so if user just write 0, there will be an error but user can write 0,5 or 0,125... **I don`t know how to manage that**

So everything is working fine except scenario 2. I don`t know how to exclude only 0... can I do that with regular expression validator, or should I try with custom validator in function(check if value is 0)

Comment: In your regex you use a dot `\.` but in your examples you use a comma `,`. A bit contradictory ...

Comment: to exclude zero, you can replace `\d` to `[1-9]` where ever you want to exclude zero in match.

Comment: HamZa, sorry \. was my mistake, I have change it with \, ...

Comment: NeverHopless but the problem is if I write [1-9] than it is also imposible to write 0,125 or 0,5 ... that I don`t want...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for decimal number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number)

Comment: M42 these example on your link allows 0 as answer, but I wan`t to exclude 0, 00, 0,0 etc.. but not 0,5 or 0,125 ... so there is a little diference (the part I needed for that : (?<![0\.]+)$ )

Comment: "wan`t" is actually spelled: "want"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could prohibit the number from containing all zeros with a [*negative lookbehind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). That would also invalidate all entries that consist of zeros and dots, but that's probably a good thing: it is very likely that since you do not want a standalone zero, you do not want `00`, `000`, or `0.000` as well:

```
^(\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,3})?)(?<!^[0\.]+)$
//                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
//                        |||
//                The lookbehind part
```

The part that I added to your expression checks that the string does not consist entirely of zeros and dots. Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/NLoz2Y).

Comment: damn, I was too quick yesterday and did not tested well the regex... Now I see that regex don`t allow numbers like 10, 100, 1000 ...

Comment: @janilemy This should fix the problem.

Comment: This was a life saver, I tested it, and I think that is perfect now ... realy many many thanks to dasblinkenlight!