# Regular expression to scan signed fixed-length decimal

Tags: c#, .net, regex, tableofcontents

How to write a regular expression to scan whether input is a signed decimal or not?

e.g:

```
-1.234567
-.1234567
123456789
1.2345678
1234567.8
-1234.567
```

Input length must be 9.

Comment: Maybe you should use a number parsing function ?

Comment: Please read #3 http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @billy I think he intends to verify if the number is in this format

Comment: @UliKöhler : True, I hadn't read the "input length must..." part.

Comment: Might have an answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number

Comment: @Zzyrk I *really* like your answer from the post linked by you, but I think it will be difficult to apply for this fixed-length case

Comment: thanks everyone. i totally forgotten about tryParse().

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using RegEx? There are better methods to determine if a string is signed or not.

Use `decimal.TryParse()` and `Math.Sign()` to get your answer.

```
string input = "-1.2342";

decimal decValue;
bool isDecimal = decimal.TryParse(input, out decValue);

if (isDecimal)
{
    int signValue = Math.Sign(decValue);
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("Not a valid decimal!");
}
```

Comment: I think he is using regex (note the word "scan" in the title) because he intends to *find* those decimals in a text.

Comment: @UliKöhler, maybe, but that's a guess at best. The question is just asking if an input is a signed decimal or not. The OP should add more information if they are asking more.

Comment: Full ACK. If you are right, you Method would of course be easier & faster then regex. However I think he wouldn't have insisted on the *exactly 9 characters* if he wouldn't want a specific recognition regex.

Comment: i totally forgotten about tryParse().

Answer (score 0):

You could do it the hard way:

```
([-\d]\d\.\d\d\d\d\d\d|[-\d]\d\d\.\d\d\d\d\d|[-\d]\d\d.\d\d\d\d|...)
```

Basically this is any of the forms you listed OR-ed. This is quite tedious, but right now I can't think of any other way that will work for all possible inputs.

Comment: Maybe with a lookahead. Assuming the nine-character length is the entire input, something like [the following](http://regexr.com?3847q):  `^(?=.{9}$)-?\d*\.?\d+$`.