# Regualr expression for decimal values

Tags: c#, regex

i need a regular expression that allows  .253 or any number followed by dot ?

here is my regular expression it allows 0.253 but not .253 ?

```
 Regex match = new Regex(@"^[0-9]\d*(\.\d*)?$");
```

Comment: Remove `[0-9]` and it would allow you `.253`.

Comment: something like `^\d*\.?\d+$`

Comment: The question is: "Why would you use regular expressions here instead of the framework solution (`decimal.TryParse`)?" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number

Comment: @Corak but i can't limit the digts before and after decimal. this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex("^[0-9]+?\.?[0-9]+$");
```

**EXPLANATION**

```
^[0-9]+?\.?[0-9]+$

Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Match a single character present in the list below «[0-9\.]*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   A . character «\.»
Match a single character in the range between “0” and “9” «[0-9]+»
   Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```

Comment: @m42 thanks for pointing that, I'm on my cellphone but I think it's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one:

```
Regex match = new Regex(@"^\d*(?:\.\d+)?$");
```