# Regular expression to check if a string is number including decimal number

Tags: regex

I want to check if a string is a number. The accepted range of numbers in my case varies a lot from large numbers with a lot of decimals like;

```
100000000000000000.000000000000000001
1
25.9897
```

Above values should be matched!

Values that should not match are;

```
10,000.4
e19
```

How can I approach this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for decimal number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968825/regular-expression-for-decimal-number)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov It is not a duplicate as the question you suggested only allows one digit before the decimal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^\d+(\.\d+)?$`

A number with any length `\d+`, then maybe some optional decimal part `(\.\d+)?`

Also important to utilize line anchors `^` and `$` to filter cases like `e19`

A possible problem can be a value like; `010.5`, leading `0`s can be kinda problematic, is that acceptable? Otherwise the way to filter values with trailing `0`s out is to use; `^[1-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`. Just FYI

[see it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4PjCmb/3)